# INSERT INTO and VALUES doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, insert

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO `Lcode` (lid, sid)
VALUES (".$a.", ".$b.")"
);
```

the above **lid=varchar and $a=vib**(in this case)
the above **sid=int and $b=3**(again in this case)

but it doesn't seem to insert it into the database?

i have checked my **connection** to the server, which is OK.

and i can either update with codes like this:

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO Lcode SET lid='".$b."'");
```

and a similar UPDATE.

i really hope u can help me with this.

**more info**

```
$a = strtolower ( $resa['lid'] );
$b = strtolower ( $resb );
```

$resa['lid'] = a variable that i get from the mysql server:: it comes back correctly when try to echo $a

$resb is a call i make to the url with a $_GET :: it does also come back correctly.

i have some troubles figuring this and need you help...

appreciate your help

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this its more easier ,

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` SET `lid` = $somevalue, `sid` = $somevalue2
```

Comment: this worked perfect thx... and also JW 웃 for the sql injection reminder... ive forgot all about that :-D

Comment: Why dont u use PDO and read this thread http:// stackoverflow.com/questions/866860/mysql-versus-pdo

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, you need to wrap the value of `lid` with single quote as it is a string literal.

```
$a = strtolower($resa['lid']);
$b = strtolower($resb);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Lcode (lid, sid) VALUES ('$a', $b)";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: $sql = ("INSERT INTO `Lcode` (lid, sid) VALUES ('$a', $c)");

it doesnt seem to work... my DB doesnt get updated with the new lid/sid

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is the lack of single quotes, like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_name` (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ('$a','$b')";
```

Try to echo whole query before sending it to server. Also use an error information from sql server to solve this, for example using mysqli:

```
echo "Error message: %s\n" . mysqli_error();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to quote your string values. This:

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO `Lcode` (lid, sid)
VALUES (".$a.", ".$b.")"
);
```

Should be:

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO `Lcode` (lid, sid)
VALUES ('".$a."', '".$b."')"
);
```

To find out these kind of problems it is very useful to print out the whole query before executing it, it should give you a clue about a possible syntax error.